# Tag title problem on Browser tab title

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that SO put tag on browser tab title like this (e.g. python) :

[image]

I'm curious how does SO determine the tag that has to be shown on the browser tab? I checked my question again and it seems the python tag is ordered first among the other tags. Then I tried to remove the python tag and put it behind of other tags, like this

[image]

After saving the edits, I hope the C++ tag will be shown at the browser tab, but it doesn't. It is still showing the Python tag instead of C++ tag, and once again the Python tag is ordered first.

Comment: Related: [Which tag is added to the page title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The tag shown in the title is the most popular tag (the one with the most number of questions).

Tags are also automatically arranged in descending order of question count when you submit your edits, regardless of the order in which you specify them.